# Did Visual Studio 2022 17.4.3 break std::round?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

(Note: This problem occurs for me only when the compiler switch `/arch:AVX` is set.   More at the bottom)

My gtest unit tests have done this for 7 years

```
ASSERT_EQ(-3.0, std::round(-2.5f));  // (Note the 'f' suffix)
```

According to [cpp-reference,](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) `std::round` is supposed to round AWAY from zero, right?  Yet with the current release, this test just started failing.  Am I missing something?    All I did was update my Visual Studio 2022 to 17.4.3  My co-worker with 17.3.3 does not have this problem

EDIT: I don't know if the problem is GTEST and its macros or assumptions my unit test makes about equality.  I put the following two lines of code into my test

```
std::cerr << "std::round(-2.5) = " << std::round(-2.5) << std::endl;
std::cerr << "std::round(-2.5f) = " << std::round(-2.5f) << std::endl;
```

They produce the following output.  The second one is wrong, is it not?

```
std::round(-2.5) = -3
std::round(-2.5f) = -2
```

EDIT #2:  As I note above, the only occurs when I set the compiler flag `/arch:AVX`  If just create a console app and do not set the flag of if I explicitly set it to `/arch:IA32`, the problem goes away.  But the question then becomes:  Is this a bug or am I just not supposed to use that option?

Comment: My first suspicion was floating point inaccuracy, but anything ending in `.5` shouldn't have that problem.

Comment: I think you should report this to the Visual Studio engineers if this is really a bug, and you can produce a [mcve] to them (probably by not using gtest, but by using `assert()` directly).

Comment: I just did that.  My report did just list the gtest line not generic code.  Still, I don't think they'll have much trouble reproducing a one-line issue this simple

Comment: What version of `cl`  does MSVS `17.4.3` correspond to?  I can't get this to fail online - live - https://godbolt.org/z/ezKnE1dze  (change the `msvc` version all I tested return `1`).

Comment: It uses 19.34.31937.

Comment: Is ASSERT_EQ a macro or a template?  std::round returns a `float`, 3.0 is a `double`.

Comment: it is a GTEST macro.  After spending a bunch of time building a test project to verify this that did use ASSERT, I could not reproduce it.  I think it's the macro

Comment: @franji1 No `std::round` is overloaded for `double` to return a `double`.

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I'm thinking it's got to be GTEST.  I think @franji1 was on to it.  At least I hope that is it.  I will update the question with more info because it's too much to type here

Comment: Is it possible that any fast-math flags have changed since upgrading your projects? These can result in differences in precision and/or the outcome of certain operations on some architectures. You could also try forcing an older architecture in the compiler (e.g. SSE3) just to see if there's something there. Otherwise I'd suspect the GTEST macro is doing something with `DBL_EPSILON`, since floating-point equality is always a touchy subject.

Comment: _"I put the following two lines of code into my test"_ — Could you please put those two lines into an ordinary `main()` function, compiled as an ordinary (non-gtest) project instead? (Just to rule out everything except the `std::round` itself.)

Comment: I just did that in my demo console app.  Same result.

Comment: @paddy Floating point model is still /fp:precise.   Just checked.

Comment: @franji1 and @user17732522 - Apologies:  My post initially neglected to show the 'f' suffix.    I have two such tests.  One uses `2.5` and the other `2.5f`.   I had the wrong one failing.  But they both should work. `f` suffix or not, should they not?

Comment: 17.4.x is rather notorious, but breaking round() would be quite a feat and nobody else is complaining about it.  Ensure the co-processor is still operating with the expected rounding mode.  Use Debug > Windows > Registers, right-click that window and tick SSE.  Ensure that the MXCSR register still contains 00001F80.

Comment: There was indeed a relatively recent change in the MS STL, switching to compiler built-ins. So maybe that isn't all that unlikely to cause new problems. See https://github.com/microsoft/STL/commit/26bbe2ad50cd7003b8220cfec2bff16dbc032ca8, although they did consider a potential rounding mode issue in https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/1234#issuecomment-682091126.

Comment: @HansPassant before and after the call to std::round that register contains 1FA0, not 1F80.   Interestingly this seems to only happen on the release build.  Even when  I disable all optimizations and intrinsics in the compiler settings.  If I run this on a debug build, the result of the std::round is -3.0.  However even in that case, the MXCSR register reads 1FA0

Comment: I have found the cause.  it is the advanced vector extensions, compiler switch `/arch:AVX`.  With this flag set, `std::round(-2.5f)` returns -2.0.  With the flag is cleared, it returns value -3.0.   So am I doing something wrong by using this setting?  Shouldn't my code still work even with them enabled?

Comment: Seems to be a recently introduced in the intrinsic which `std::round(float)` is forwarded to, but not the library implementation: https://godbolt.org/z/898eE1es9 (I assume it is a bug, but am not sure.)

Comment: You can report the problem to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug, see the [bug report on developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/AVX-std::round-on-float-different-from-S/10221658?sort=newest&q=round), which is already in the "pending release" state.

For completeness/standalone sake, the minimal example from there is ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/9WGjP7dPh)):

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "MSVC version: " << _MSC_FULL_VER << '\n';
    std::cout << "Round 0.5f: " << std::round(0.5f) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Round 0.5: " << std::round(0.5) << '\n';
}
```

compiled with AVX or AVX2.
The correct output e.g. with MSVC 19.33 is

```
MSVC version: 193331631
Round 0.5f: 1
Round 0.5: 1
```

while the latest MSVC 19.34 outputs

```
MSVC version: 193431931
Round 0.5f: 0
Round 0.5: 1
```

Comment: Had them close my developer community issue in favor of that one.  Fixed in 17.5, they say